# Pandas Logic - Room For Dynamic Programming

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Please view Example DataFrame and my code below. Here are my step by step goals: **Step 1:** Combine Column A and Column B into Column_A_B **Step 2:** Count each instance of the values in 'ColumnA_B' **Step 3** Filter out rows where there is only 1 instance of the value in 'ColumnA_B' **Step 4**: Delete each row that has cancelled in the 'Status' Column, and just the row that has canceled in it - there may be some with the same value in ColumnA_B but different "Status' values ( note while the Step three filter is being applied) **My code before step five seems to work, its just the step five I am really stuck on** **Step 5:** With the filter still on for 'Column_A_B' ( ie the filtering out count of 1) look at the redundant values ( so when you count the values in 'Column_A_B_' is would be 2 or greater) and then for said grouped counts look at the 'Qty' column. If this group has a Qty of less than 16 AND over 99 delete just the row that had 'QTY' of 16. IF the grouping had "QTY's of all less than 99 don't delete anything , if all the 'QTY' values are over 99 dont delete anything.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import NaN
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_A':['test1', 'test7', 'test7', 'test4', 'test6', 'test6', 'test7'],'Column_B':['WO1','WO7', 'WO7', 'WO6', 'WO6', 'WO6', 'WO7'],
                   'Column_A_B': ['','','','','','','',], 'Status': ['Cancelled','Cancelled', 'Active', 'Active', 'Open', 'Active', 'Active'],
                   'Qty': ['12', '34' , '13', '3000', '14', '88', '1500']})
df_deleted = df.copy(deep=True)
df_deleted.drop(df.index,inplace=True)
LOWER_THRESHOLD = 16

print("1. combine col A & B ")
for i, row in df.iterrows(): #iterate through each row with with row value and row content
    a = str(row['Column_A'])
    b = str(row['Column_B'])

    concat = a + b

    df.set_value(i, 'Column_A_B', concat)

#worked 2.21
print('2. Count all the duplicates of the combined values above')
seen = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows(): # now we will count the combined values, not dict keys cant have dupe values
    c = row['Column_A_B']

    if c not in seen: # have not seen the letter before, we need to establish this
        seen [c] = 0

    seen[c] += 1 # Seen concatted values once, add one.
for i, row in df.iterrows(): #put the recorded numbers in, now we loop thorugh each row to get the value of c to call it as it's key (dict) value
    c = row['Column_A_B']

    times_seen = seen[c]

    df.set_value(i, 'Count_Of_Value', times_seen)

#worked 2.21
print("3. Ignore instances of rowes  where concat is not one, assign column True if count is 1 else false")
for i, row in df.iterrows():
      d = row['Count_Of_Value']
      if d == 1.0:
          df.set_value(i,'True_False',True)
      else:
          df.set_value(i,'True_False',False)

#worked 2.21
print('4. Delete all rows where orders are cancelled but concated column is more than 1')
delete_these = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
      f = row['Status']
      d = row['True_False']

      if str(f) == 'Cancelled' and d != True: 
          delete_these.append(i)
          df_deleted = df_deleted.append(row) 

df.drop(delete_these, axis=0, inplace=True)



#worked 2.21 on this small df
print('step 5. Delete qty where Column_A_B is the same, has more than 1 instance, and if said grouping has a Qty above 99 and below 16, delete the value below 16, if the grouping of values all have qtys less than 100 or over 100 dont delte anything')
over_numbers = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows(): 
      c = row['Column_A_B'] # 2.21 this appears to be where the error is, trying to replace combined column w/ wo
      g = row['Qty']
      d = c + str(random.randint(1,10000000)) #attempting to create unique value
      df.set_value(i, 'test', d) # make column to match unique value for each qty

      if float(g) > float(99):
          over_numbers[d] = True
print(over_numbers)
## this issue is that it is storing values that are dupicated, so the below doesnt know which one to assing T/F to 2.21
for i, row in df.iterrows(): # storing the numbers over 99
    c = row['test'] # loop through unique value

    if c in over_numbers:
        df.set_value(i, 'Comments_Status',True)
    else:
        df.set_value(i,'Comments_Status',False)
## the above appeared to lable True/False correct after adding unique values to combined column 2.21
delete_these = []

for i, row in df.iterrows(): # Remove all rows that have over_number = True and also number less than 16
    d = row['Qty'] # should this be changed?
    f = row['Comments_Status']
    z = row['test']

    if int(d) <= int(16) and f is True: # so grouping 1st arts
        delete_these.append(i) # store row number to drop later
        df_deleted = df_deleted.append(row) # Add the row to other dataframe

df.drop(delete_these, axis=0, inplace=True)


# end
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('keep.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('deleted.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df_deleted.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

**What I want the dataframe above to look like when the program is done ( which above I have named keep.xlsx) should look like this:**

```
import pandas as pd

goaldf = pd.DataFrame({'Column_A':['test1', 'test4', 'test6', 'test6', 'test7'],'Column_B':['WO1', 'WO6', 'WO6', 'WO6', 'WO7'],
                   'Column_A_B': ['test1W01','test4WO6','test6WO6','test6WO6', 'test7WO7'], 'Satus': ['Cancelled', 'Active', 'Open', 'Active', 'Active'],
                   'Qty': ['12', '3000', '14', '88', '1500']})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('goaldf.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
goaldf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: i really dont understand your logic at step 5, i dont understant if you do the sum of Qty or not when you group by column_AB, could you explain your logic with a concrete sample, showing different case

Comment: @Frenchy  thanks for the time & when I get to a machine (on mobile rn) I will provide more detail. But first I’ll answer your question no you do not “sum” the qty. you count the how many times the value of Column__A_B ( for example ‘test6WO6 ‘ has a count of two in the df above and let’s call that a “grouping” ) so for each grouping then you look @ each lines respective order qty so the “test6WO6” grouping has two order qtys 14 & 88 - now we analyze these qtys with the logic that if there is a over 99 and under 16 delete the 16 . In his exact example they are 14 and 88 so none get deleted

Comment: *** edit second to last sentence - you delete whatever row had a qty that was under 16 not “delete the 16”

Comment: i have updated the solution following your explanations..hope ist ok

Comment: @Frenchy Thank you so much, this def works for the test dataset, I will mark as complete for now for your credit, but maybe I Will comment @ you again for any questions on larger data sets ( but this should work fine). If you could would you mind explaining **Step 1 & Step 5** , or if your limited on time really just this block df['maxAB'] = df.groupby('Column_A_B')['Qty'].transform('max')  
todelete = df[(df['maxAB'] > 99) & (df['Qty'] <= 16)]
df= df[(df['maxAB'] <= 99) | (df['Qty'] > 16)]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: i have added some explanations in Answer to help you to understand...

Comment: @Frenchy thank you !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following your explanations:

```
"""
goal waiting
  Column_A Column_B Column_A_B     Status   Qty
0    test1      WO1   test1W01  Cancelled    12
1    test4      WO6   test4WO6     Active  3000
2    test6      WO6   test6WO6       Open    14
3    test6      WO6   test6WO6     Active    88
4    test7      WO7   test7WO7     Active  1500
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import NaN

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_A':['test1', 'test7', 'test7', 'test4', 'test6', 'test6', 'test7'],'Column_B':['WO1','WO7', 'WO7', 'WO6', 'WO6', 'WO6', 'WO7'],
                   'Status': ['Cancelled','Cancelled', 'Active', 'Active', 'Open', 'Active', 'Active'],
                   'Qty': ['12', '34' , '13', '3000', '14', '88', '1500']})

df_deleted = df.copy(deep=True)
df_deleted.drop(df.index,inplace=True)

#Step1
def process(r):
    return r['Column_A'] + r['Column_B']
df["Column_A_B"] = df.apply(lambda row: process(row), axis = 1)
print("step 1");print(df)

#Step2
df['countAB'] = df.groupby('Column_A_B')['Qty'].transform('count')
print("step 2");print(df)

#Step3
df['True_False']=df['countAB'] == 1
print("step 3");print(df)

#Step4
todelete = df[(df['Status'] == 'Cancelled') & (df['True_False'] == False)]
df = df[(df['Status'] != 'Cancelled') | (df['True_False'] == True)]
df.drop(['countAB','True_False'], axis=1, inplace=True)
todelete.drop(['True_False', 'countAB'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_deleted = df_deleted.append(todelete)
print("step 4");print(df);print("step 4 - deleted");print(df_deleted)

#5tep5
df['Qty'] = df['Qty'].astype(int)
df['maxAB'] = df.groupby('Column_A_B')['Qty'].transform('max')  
todelete = df[(df['maxAB'] > 99) & (df['Qty'] <= 16)]
df= df[(df['maxAB'] <= 99) | (df['Qty'] > 16)]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
todelete.drop(['maxAB'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_deleted = df_deleted.append(todelete)
df.drop(['maxAB'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print("step 5");print(df);print("step 5 - deleted");print(df_deleted)
```

output:

```
  Column_A Column_B     Status   Qty Column_A_B
0    test1      WO1  Cancelled    12   test1WO1
1    test4      WO6     Active  3000   test4WO6
2    test6      WO6       Open    14   test6WO6
3    test6      WO6     Active    88   test6WO6
4    test7      WO7     Active  1500   test7WO7
step 5 - deleted
  Column_A Column_A_B Column_B Qty     Status
1    test7   test7WO7      WO7  34  Cancelled
2    test7   test7WO7      WO7  13     Active
```

**Some explanations:**

**For Step1:**

Its just concatenation of 2 columns with a lambda, when you are using apply, you do something on every row (axis = 1)
The result is in a new column "Column_A_B"

```
#Step1

# definition of lambda function (others ways to do exist)
def process(r):
    return r['Column_A'] + r['Column_B'] # i concatenate the 2 values

df["Column_A_B"] = df.apply(lambda row: process(row), axis = 1)
print("step 1");print(df)
```

result:

```
step 1
  Column_A Column_B     Status   Qty Column_A_B
0    test1      WO1  Cancelled    12   test1WO1
1    test7      WO7  Cancelled    34   test7WO7
2    test7      WO7     Active    13   test7WO7
3    test4      WO6     Active  3000   test4WO6
4    test6      WO6       Open    14   test6WO6
5    test6      WO6     Active    88   test6WO6
6    test7      WO7     Active  1500   test7WO7
```

**For step5:**

the idea is to create a new column with the max value of Qty in each group (here the group is Column_A_B), so after this command:

```
df['maxAB'] = df.groupby('Column_A_B')['Qty'].transform('max') 
print("maxAB");print(df)
```

the result:

```
maxAB
  Column_A Column_B     Status   Qty Column_A_B  maxAB
0    test1      WO1  Cancelled    12   test1WO1     12  *max value of group test1WO1
2    test7      WO7     Active    13   test7WO7   1500  *max value of group test7WO7
3    test4      WO6     Active  3000   test4WO6   3000  *max value of group test4WO6
4    test6      WO6       Open    14   test6WO6     88  *max value of group test6WO6
5    test6      WO6     Active    88   test6WO6     88  *max value of group test6WO6
6    test7      WO7     Active  1500   test7WO7   1500  *max value of group test7WO7
```

As you see you have the max value of each group in front of itself (sorry for my english)

Now for each group which have a Qty > 99 and a Qty <=16, i delete only the the rows which have the Qty <= 16.

So the next command says that: i keep all rows which answer to this filter and put to todelete dataframe

```
todelete = df[(df['maxAB'] > 99) & (df['Qty'] <= 16)]
```

So in todelete i want to keep, but in df i want to delete (and keep all others rows).
We have to use the opposite filter.

> in logic => **A and b**, the opposite **not ( A and B) =  (not A) or (not B)**

so the "not" logic of

```
df[(df['maxAB'] > 99) & (df['Qty'] <= 16)]
```

is:

```
df[(df['maxAB'] <= 99) | (df['Qty'] > 16)]
```

so after this command:

```
# i want to keep rows which have a Qty <= 99 
#             or 
# rows which have a Qty > 16
df= df[(df['maxAB'] <= 99) | (df['Qty'] > 16)]
```

you could simplify by using a variable:

```
filter = (df['maxAB'] > 99) & (df['Qty'] <= 16)
todelete = df[filter]
df= df[~filter]
```

**~filter** is equivalent at **not filter**

i rebuild the index (0 to 4)

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

finally, you have the final result waited (after dropping the temporary columns)

hope this helps to understand...